# Call not working as a chained function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following snippet of code :

```
$('#move').click(function () {
    $('#block').animate({
        'left': '+=50px'
    }, 500);
});

function get_fx() {
    var store = console.log($(this).queue('fx').length);
    return store;
}

function trigger_it(param) {
    $(param).trigger('click');
}

call_it = setInterval(function () {
    trigger_it('#move')
},
2000);
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8xq5f2j/)

Now, after the animate function has been run on `$('#block')`, I would like the `get_fx()` function to return the number of animations still in the queue for `$('#block')`, so I have the following line of code, after the animate function :

```
.call(this , get_fx())
```

Now this actually seems to work, but let me show you the result I get in the console :

```
0 // 0 is displayed , which i guess is the correct result .. I am not sure . 
TypeError: $(...).animate(...).call is not a function // I get this error , I don't know why .
```

Now can somebody tell me why am I getting that error and is my call function doing what its suppose to do ?

**EDIT::** I don't want to go with the **callback** option of the animate function instead i want to use the **call** function on get_fx() .

Comment: Thank you for the vote up , it really encourages me to learn more , i am new to Jquery , thank you soo much ! . Please also answer the question though .

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u8xq5f2j/21/ ?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks , why the error was showing though in my code ?

Comment: I created a plugin called `call` which is doing the actual work of calling `get_fx`..if this solved the problem I can post it as an answer

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't see any plugin in th external resources in your fiddle , are u not using the call function is javascript I.E prototype.call() ??

Comment: see `jQuery.fn.call = function(callback){}` - this creates a plugin called `call`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70684/discussion-between-alexander-solonik-and-arun-p-johny).

Answer (score 1):

```
    animate()
```

function support call back function. You can utilise this. So you can use like this

```
        $('#move').click(function(){
            $('#block').animate({ 'left' : '+=50px' } , 500, function(){

                 get_fx();

            });
```

Comment: thanks ! but i really want to use the call() function . i am aware of the callback option . I'll vote u up though .